# How do I add a add_rewrite_rule without it redirecting?

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type called "locations".

I have a location called "starbucks". I can view this by going to "/location/starbucks".

I would like to add "coffee-shop" to the URL, so the path "/location/coffee-shop/starbucks" will load the "starbucks" page, while maintaining the URL in the browser.

i have added this code to my functions.php

```
function add_rewrite_rules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^location/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=$matches[2]','top');
}

add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Which correctly loads the "starbucks" page, but it changes the URL to "/location/starbucks".

How can I load the "starbucks" page, and keep my custom URL?

Comment: Try `location=$matches[2]`, not `pagename`.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic that loaded the homepage.

Comment: Whoops, try `locations` instead (note the plural).

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thanks! Please add your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Nice one. Will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your rewrite rule, `pagename` should in fact be the `query_var` of your custom post type. Unless you used `query_var => 'something_else'` in your `register_post_type` arguments, it'll be the same name as your custom post type:

```
index.php?locations=$matches[2]
```