# Have two different URLs show the homepage

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I want to have two different URLs for the same page. In particular I want to have a specific URL that shows my frontpage. The URL should be kept however. So these two URLs

```
www.mywebsite.com/
www.mywebsite.com/page1
```

should both be displaying the frontpage. I thought this could be done with WordPress's `add_rewrite_rule` function, but I didn't have success with that yet.

When I do this

```
add_rewrite_rule('^page1', 'index.php', 'top');
```

It acts more like a redirect. When I try to access `www.mywebsite.com/page1` I get redirected to my homepage. But I want the URL to stay the same, which this doesn't seem to do.

When I do this

```
add_rewrite_rule('^page1', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

it just shows the page www.mywebsite.com/page1 instead of the homepage.

I fumbled around with the rewrite rules for hours now and I'm pretty much at my wits end. Is what I want even possible?

---

**Edit:** This is different from many other questions in that I am trying to show the frontpage. The solution provided [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147855/how-do-i-add-a-add-rewrite-rule-without-it-redirecting) solves this, when you can use the locations query var, but I didn't get it to work with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a add\_rewrite\_rule without it redirecting?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147855/how-do-i-add-a-add-rewrite-rule-without-it-redirecting)

Comment: However, you shouldn't do this. It's very bad for SEO, it would be normally considered duplicate content. It would be better for you to add an additional landing page to your site.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I don't make that decision. Had these concerns as well, but it has to be done...

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. I think I can't use 'locations" in my query, because I'm pointing to my homepage.

Comment: Under Settings > Reading, what is **Your homepage displays** set to?

Comment: "A static page", namely my homepage.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress will always try to redirect to the canonical URL to prevent duplicate content, so you'll have to disable that mechanism to get another URL to display that page.

First, your rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^page1', 'index.php?pagename=your-page-name', 'top');
```

Then filter `redirect_canonical` to return false if the requested URL is your 2nd home URL:

```
function my_redir_check( $redirect_url, $requested_url ){
    if( home_url( '/page1/' ) == trailingslashit( $requested_url ) ){
        return false;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'my_redir_check', 10, 2 );
```